# Angularjs Div Show, Hide Toggle with adding class to active button

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to this please bear with me

I'm trying to achieve div toggle and button class added when button clicked (active), i looked every where i been trying to do this for over 6 hours now :(.

here is my NAV div

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper-button" ng-controller="Main">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-click="isInfo = !isInfo" ng-class="{'active':isInfo}"><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></a></li>
        <li ng-click="isSetting = !isSetting" ng-class="{'active':isSetting}"><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Content Div

```
<div ng-class="{'ng-show':isSetting,'ng-hide':!isSetting,'ng-hide':isInfo,}">
    <h1>Setting</h1>
</div>

<div ng-class="{'ng-show':isInfo,'ng-hide':!isInfo,'ng-hide':isSetting}">
    <h1>Info</h1>
</div>
```

app.js

```
//toggle Setting
app.controller('Main', function($scope) {
    $scope.isSetting = false;
});
//toggle Info
app.controller('Main', function($scope) {
    $scope.isInfo = false;
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: One small change which may not alter what is happening is to use 'ng-show="isSetting"' in place of ng-class="{'ng-show':isSetting... Same with ng-hide as an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your request right, here's what I would do:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Main', function($scope) {
    $scope.tabActive = null; // here insert 1, 2 or null depending on what the initial selection should be
});
```

```css
li a{text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Main">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li ng-click="tabActive = 1" ng-class="{'active':tabActive == 1}">
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-info"></a>
      </li>
      
      <li ng-click="tabActive = 2" ng-class="{'active':tabActive == 2}">
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-cog"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-show="tabActive == 1">
       <h1>Info</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="tabActive == 2">
      <h1>Setting</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way is to use angular expression `{{}}` to output appropriate string:

```
<h1>{{isSetting ? 'Setting' : 'Info'}}</h1>
```

Requires less markup and less class change logic code and ultimately less scope watches